# VFD speed reference command: Will MODBUS/TCP have better resolution than 4.0 ~ 20.0 mA

Tags: vfd, modbus

I need help to understand the difference between tranditional 4.0~20.0 mA and digital communication (for example MODBUS/TCP)

Assume: a PLC communicates with a VFD to control a variable speed pump from 0%~100% with 0% representing 0 rpm and 100% representing full speed.

Case 1: the PLC uses 4.0~20.0 mA analog signal as speed reference signal

Case 2: the PLC sends 0.0~100.0 as 32 bits floating number using MODBUS/TCP

In general sense, will MODBUS/TCP achieve better speed resolution than 4.0~20.0 mA as speed reference signal to VFD?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This always depends on the hardware implementation, there is no general rule. We can only compare two concrete solutions. It is not always the case, that the higher resolution of the 32 bit float reaches the driver hardware and the response time can be worse.

Comment: Thanks Jens. But we are all moving towards digital communication now days. Network reliability is going to be a total different topic.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to pore through the manuals for both the VFD and the PLC to see what all is limiting the resolution. And the information may not even be there.

You can be pretty sure that the resolution is not going to be anything like 32 bits regardless of how you send the speed command. Typical PLC/VFD ADC and DAC resolutions are 12 or 16 bits. A sensorless VFD might have 0.01Hz resolution in the control section so about 12.5 bits @ 60Hz.

Generally you'd probably want to use digital communication for stability reasons anyway though.

Comment: A float is not giving 32 bits of resolution, but still more than a typical ADC / DAC combination of a PLC and analog input stage.

Comment: @Arsenal If the 32-bit float mantissa is 24 bits, the 4-20mA input ADC is 16 bits, and the VFD synthesis is 12.5 bits there will be no *significant* difference in resolution between analog and digital input. Stability should be better with all digital. Bandwidth might be a consideration.

Comment: With analog 4.0 mA ~ 20.0 mA case, 1. the PLC has to do a DAC to transfer the control signal (which is a float number) to mA. 2. On receiving the mA signal, the VFD does a ADC to get the float number 3. VFD generates corresponding frequency for the pump. With digital communication, VFD will directly generates the corresponding frequency on receiving the float number from PLC, by passing the DAC and ADC steps. Am I right?

Comment: @RXS Yes, I think that's a likely signal chain (modulo the internal details of how the VFD does calculations .. fixed point may be used rather than floats).

Comment: Thanks @Spehro. Just checked one VFD, command 20,000 representing 100% full speed

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the Modbus TCP to be better:

- It's generated by the VFD and transmitted without any conversion. It's what the VFD thinks is going on.
- The 4 - 20 mA transmission will require a DAC output conversion on the VFD end and a DAC conversion on the PLC input. There are always going to be errors with this method.

Check the speed of updates. I don't expect that it's going to be a problem.